# How to add array element check (IN SQL operation) in left outer join?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have this SQL Query

```
SELECT [c].[ClinicID], [c0].[ClinicNotificationId], [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId], [c0].[ClinicId], [c0].[DoctorId], [c0].[Email], [c0].[NotificationType], [c0].[SMS]
FROM [Clinic] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [ClinicNotificationRecipient] AS [c0] ON [c].[ClinicID] = [c0].[ClinicId] and 
[c0].[AccountRoleMemberId] IN (N'2663c1dc-b414-43a8-9a89-8ff76ebd87e1', N'34273572-b322-45c1-9c95-ce00d29e843d', N'3be573bc-499e-40ba-b245-ce7950123d25', N'6ad82ec2-f7a5-4550-84f2-c3531a2909bf', N'6dd9ac49-8c46-491a-84db-6807efd04935', N'70e47962-4509-4f70-b958-e0eaeced07a8', N'70f651fc-9df8-4342-9678-433b0e63717e', N'b469cd6e-ceb0-46f8-b70e-045c6afcb207', N'b7aa5a0b-f00d-4c28-9ba5-745dcf77135d', N'f6425f8e-f124-4e64-ba6b-ea11bfd81078', N'ff4cedad-80b3-498c-b1ff-e893a18aea09')
WHERE (([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[DoctorID] = @__doctorid_0))
```

I would like to perform this query in LINQ C#. At first I tried this LINQ query:

```
var q = from c in Clinic
            join cnr in ClinicNotificationRecipient on c.ClinicID equals cnr.ClinicId into g
            from gcnr in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where c.Active == true && c.DoctorID == doctorid && (gcnr == null || subUserAcctRoleMemberIds.Contains(gcnr.AccountRoleMemberId))
            select new {
                c.ClinicID,
                cnr = gcnr
            };
```

however this gave me this sql query

```
SELECT [c].[ClinicID], [c0].[ClinicNotificationId], [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId], [c0].[ClinicId], [c0].[DoctorId], [c0].[Email], [c0].[NotificationType], [c0].[SMS]
FROM [Clinic] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [ClinicNotificationRecipient] AS [c0] ON [c].[ClinicID] = [c0].[ClinicId]
WHERE (([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[DoctorID] = @__doctorid_0)) AND (([c0].[ClinicNotificationId] IS NULL OR [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId] IS NULL) OR [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId] IN (N'2663c1dc-b414-43a8-9a89-8ff76ebd87e1', N'34273572-b322-45c1-9c95-ce00d29e843d', N'3be573bc-499e-40ba-b245-ce7950123d25', N'6ad82ec2-f7a5-4550-84f2-c3531a2909bf', N'6dd9ac49-8c46-491a-84db-6807efd04935', N'70e47962-4509-4f70-b958-e0eaeced07a8', N'70f651fc-9df8-4342-9678-433b0e63717e', N'b469cd6e-ceb0-46f8-b70e-045c6afcb207', N'b7aa5a0b-f00d-4c28-9ba5-745dcf77135d', N'f6425f8e-f124-4e64-ba6b-ea11bfd81078', N'ff4cedad-80b3-498c-b1ff-e893a18aea09'))
```

How can I move the `IN` condition as part of the left join operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this with this query.

```
var q = from c in Clinic
            join cnr in ClinicNotificationRecipient.Where(x => subUserAcctRoleMemberIds.Contains(x.AccountRoleMemberId))
            on c.ClinicID equals cnr.ClinicId into g
            from gcnr in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            let ids = subUserAcctRoleMemberIds
            where c.Active == true && c.DoctorID == doctorid
            select new {
                c.ClinicID,
                cnr = gcnr
            };
```

this produced the following sql query:

```
SELECT [c].[ClinicID], [t].[ClinicNotificationId], [t].[AccountRoleMemberId], [t].[ClinicId], [t].[DoctorId], [t].[Email], [t].[NotificationType], [t].[SMS]
FROM [Clinic] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [c0].[ClinicNotificationId], [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId], [c0].[ClinicId], [c0].[DoctorId], [c0].[Email], [c0].[NotificationType], [c0].[SMS]
    FROM [ClinicNotificationRecipient] AS [c0]
    WHERE [c0].[AccountRoleMemberId] IN (N'2663c1dc-b414-43a8-9a89-8ff76ebd87e1', N'34273572-b322-45c1-9c95-ce00d29e843d', N'3be573bc-499e-40ba-b245-ce7950123d25', N'6ad82ec2-f7a5-4550-84f2-c3531a2909bf', N'6dd9ac49-8c46-491a-84db-6807efd04935', N'70e47962-4509-4f70-b958-e0eaeced07a8', N'70f651fc-9df8-4342-9678-433b0e63717e', N'b469cd6e-ceb0-46f8-b70e-045c6afcb207', N'b7aa5a0b-f00d-4c28-9ba5-745dcf77135d', N'f6425f8e-f124-4e64-ba6b-ea11bfd81078', N'ff4cedad-80b3-498c-b1ff-e893a18aea09')
) AS [t] ON [c].[ClinicID] = [t].[ClinicId]
WHERE ([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[DoctorID] = @__doctorid_0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original query, you have the `ClinicNotificationRecipient` filter against the array in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN`

The correct way to match this in LINQ is to place it *before* `DefaultIfEmpty()`

```cs
var q = from c in Clinic
        join cnr in ClinicNotificationRecipient on c.ClinicID equals cnr.ClinicId into g
        from gcnr in g.Where(gcnr2 => subUserAcctRoleMemberIds.Contains(gcnr2.AccountRoleMemberId)).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where c.Active == true && c.DoctorID == doctorid
        select new {
            c.ClinicID,
            cnr = gcnr
        };
```

Comment: I got this error

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Clinic>()
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: DbSet<ClinicNotificationRecipient>(), 
        outerKeySelector: c => (Nullable<int>)c.ClinicID, 
        innerKeySelector: cnr => cnr.ClinicId, 
        resultSelector: (c, g) => new { 
            c = c, 
            g = g
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.